# numdisplay ds9 crashes on Debian linux

Tags: python, linux

I started to use python as an astronomer and I have been using the package numdisplay to display and manipulate images on SAO ds9.
The computer lab of my university has recently updated the linux version to Debian 7.1.
I am running python 2.7.3 with python 0.13.1 and numdisplay v.1.5.6, pyds9 v.1.7 and pyfits v2.3.1.

I am using the display procedure given in http://stsdas.stsci.edu/perry/pydatatut.pdf.

Once loaded  a fits image and opened the ds9 interface, I try to display the image on ds9 but the ds9 crashes.
Hereafter the steps I use in interactive mode:

> In [2]: import pyfits as pf
>
> In [3]: import numdisplay as nd
>
> In [4]: import ds9
>
> In [5]: ds9.ds9()
>
> Out[5]: ds9.ds9 at 0xa3e870c
>
> In [6]: im = pf.getdata('M52b.fit')
>
> In [7]: nd.display(im)

and I get the following error message:

```
    error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-7-6988a1e88909> in <module>()
----> 1 nd.display(im)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numdisplay/__init__.pyc in display(self, pix, name, bufname, z1, z2, transform, zscale, contrast, scale, offset, frame)
    395 
    396         # Initialize the specified frame buffer
--> 397         _d.setFrame(self.frame)
    398         _d.eraseFrame()
    399 

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numdisplay/displaydev.pyc in setFrame(self, frame_num)
    405 
    406         code = self._LUT | self._COMMAND
--> 407         self._writeHeader(self._IIS_WRITE, code, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    408 
    409         # Update with user specified frame number

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numdisplay/displaydev.pyc in _writeHeader(self, tid, subunit, thingct, x, y, z, t)
    540         sum = 0xffff - (sum & 0xffff)
    541         a[3] = sum 
--> 542         self._write(a.tostring())
    543 
    544     def close(self, os_close=os.close):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numdisplay/displaydev.pyc in _write(self, s)
    578             n = len(s)
    579             while n>0:
--> 580                 nwritten = self._socket.send(s[-n:])
    581                 n -= nwritten
    582                 if nwritten <= 0:
    
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

In [8]:
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you

Marco

Answer (score 0):

The error message means "I was sending data but the remote side suddenly closed the connection."

So you need to check the error log of the server to find out what the problem was. This doesn't mean the client is correct or not (the client might send illegal data to the server making it crash) but you need to debug the server **first** to find out what the reason for the aborted connection is.